# Executing for loop with two inputs

Tags: linux, loops

I am using for-loop to execute my command in linux. I have 20 files in one input and 20 files in another input

```
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074*.nc;
do;
f2={avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc};
command $f1 $f2 output;
done
```

It is not reading the second input.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolons:

```
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074*.nc;
do;
f2={avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc};
command $f1 $f2 output;
done
```

are useless.

```
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074*.nc
do
  f2={avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc}
  command $f1 $f2 output
done
```

Line 3 is fishy. What do you want to do? Create an array?

```
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074*.nc
do
  f2=(avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc)
  command "$f1" "${f2[@]}" output
done
```

To loop over, let's say 20 files, matching pattern f1, and call each with let's say 20 files matching f2:

```
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074*.nc
do
  f2=avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc
  command "$f1" $f2 output
done
```

This would lead to 20 command invocations, rolling through f1 but each called with all the files matching f2.

For 20x20 matches, you would use a second loop. 
Fitted to file patterns on my harddrive:

```
for f1 in file1*; do  f2=sample.*;  echo command "$f1" $f2* output; done
command file1 sample.conf sample.go sample.log sample.xml output
command file1.txt sample.conf sample.go sample.log sample.xml output
command file1nums sample.conf sample.go sample.log sample.xml output
```

You would of course use your patterns and, after testing, remove the *echo*.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have run the code in your last comment. It gives an error                                                                                                  cdo ydayadd: Open failed on >avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc< . I did executed this command using 1 file from each inputs and it is working fine but I am not getting how to run it in loop.

Comment: The loop is not taking values from second input i.e. from f2=avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc

Comment: So what does `ls avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc` and `ls $f2` show? Maybe a typo? Wrong directory? Does the filename include whitespace?

Comment: ls avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc show the input files which are basically 20 input models and $f2 I have used to take these input files for every corresponding input file in $f1. I will write the command to help explain the single command execution with two inputs. The command is:  cdo ydayadd zero-mam-2025-2049-tasmax-ACCESS1-0-RCP85-2006-2099_Pak_0.25.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-ACCESS1-0-Historical-1976-2005_Pak_0.25.nc output_file.nc

Comment: The single command is working fine. I wish to execute it in loop taking 20 files form input 1 and at the same time taking 20 files from input 2 and perform the command.

Comment: OK, I changed the 2nd from last block and added the last one.

Comment: It is working now but it is printing 20 combinations for every input in file . i.e. it printing 20 times the combinations. My output will be simple just 20 files in the output. my command will give result like f1=0 and f2=2  the output=2

Comment: Actually I got the reason why it is not working. if in f2=avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc I give only one file it works fine and gives me 20 files in the output but when i use *.nc it failed. It is not taking multiple inputs. I think i have to initiate while loop in it,may be

Comment: I have introduced two for loops and it is working                                    
  for i in zero*.nc do for j in avm*.nc do command "$i" "$j" output done done. The loop is running infinitely and for each i it is not taking exact j

Comment: @JahangirAli: comments are a bad place to write/read code and we need to see the whole code to find the error. Write a new question - you may link from there to here and from a comment here to there or use a tool like https://www.shellcheck.net/ to find your bug. Or eventually extend your question without destroying the original content.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703934/two-for-loops-linux-with-two-input-files